# Prevent Android Fragment from Being Recreated on Device Rotate

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

### The Problem:

When I rotate my device, the information contained within my fragment in my app is reloaded. Since this app pulls information from the internet, this means, a lack of data for some time while data is being recollected.

### What I have Tried:

I have read many articles and S/O questions that give a few general pointers and have tried their solutions, from `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in the manifest to adding `setRetainInstance(true);` in both my `MainActivity` and `FragmentActivity`. Neither of these have worked to keep my fragment from reloading. I used the `android:configChanges` in another activity in the app (A detail activity, which activates when a user selects a news story) and it works properly there, preventing the activity from reloading.

### Structure of My App:

This is a simple app that pulls data from the "Hacker News" API and shows it to the user. There is a NavigationDrawer for the user to select different news types. Each item in the NavigationDrawer is a different Fragment that loads in the `MainActivity.class`. The Fragment in question here is `HomeFragment.class` which loads the main news stories.

### Why I'm asking here:

I can't seem to find anything that works with the structure of my app as it currently stands, so I would like some help in trying to find a solution for this seemingly trivial (but confusing) problem.

### Code:

#### MainActivity.java

```
package com.material.tdapps.hackernews.activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.material.tdapps.hackernews.R;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar appToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(appToolbar);

        //noinspection ConstantConditions
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        FragmentDrawer drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), appToolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

        displayView(0);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        return id == R.id.action_settings || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
        displayView(position);
    }

    private void displayView(int position){
        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_news);
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new ShowFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_show);
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new AskFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_ask);
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new JobsFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_job);
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }

        if (fragment != null){
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);

        }
    }


}
```

#### HomeFragment.java

```
package com.material.tdapps.hackernews.activity;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.material.tdapps.hackernews.JSON.JSONNewsParser;
import com.material.tdapps.hackernews.R;
import com.material.tdapps.hackernews.model.StoryFeed;
import com.material.tdapps.hackernews.model.StoryItem;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    StoryFeed storyFeed;
    Context context;
    ListView listView;
    NewsListAdapter newsListAdapter;

    public HomeFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        context = this.getActivity();
        storyFeed = new StoryFeed();
        newsListAdapter = new NewsListAdapter(this);
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.newsListView);
        if (savedInstanceState != null && (savedInstanceState.getSerializable("previousFeed") != null)) {
            Log.e("NOTIFY >> ", "GOING TO BUNDLE");
            storyFeed = (StoryFeed)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("previousFeed");
            listView.setAdapter(newsListAdapter);
            newsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            Log.e("NOTIFY >> ", "GOING TO ASYNCTASK");
            new AsyncLoadNewsFeed().execute();
            listView.setAdapter(newsListAdapter);
        }

        setRetainInstance(true);

        return rootView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    private class AsyncLoadNewsFeed extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            JSONNewsParser newsParser = new JSONNewsParser();
            storyFeed = newsParser.parseJSON("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json",0,30);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            if (storyFeed == null || storyFeed.getStoryCount() == 0){
                StoryItem nullStoryItem = new StoryItem();
                nullStoryItem.setTitle("ERROR: Null error!");
                nullStoryItem.setNumberComments(0);
                nullStoryItem.setScore(0);
                nullStoryItem.setBodyText("NULL");
                nullStoryItem.setTime(0);
                nullStoryItem.setAuthor("NULL");
                nullStoryItem.setUrl("http://www.google.com");
                storyFeed.addStory(nullStoryItem);
            }
            newsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    class NewsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public NewsListAdapter(HomeFragment homeFragment){
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) homeFragment.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return storyFeed.getStoryCount();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        class listViewHolder {

            TextView titleTxtV;
            TextView timeTxtV;
            TextView scoreTxtV;
            TextView authorTxtV;
            TextView domTxtV;
            Button commentB;
            RelativeLayout detailsLayout;

            listViewHolder(View v) {
                titleTxtV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
                timeTxtV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.timeText);
                scoreTxtV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pointsText);
                authorTxtV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.authorText);
                domTxtV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.domainText);
                commentB = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.commentButton);
                detailsLayout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.newsDetailRelLayout);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View listItem = convertView;
            listViewHolder holder;

            if (listItem == null) {
                listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.news_item_layout, parent, false );
                holder = new listViewHolder(listItem);
                listItem.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (listViewHolder) listItem.getTag();
            }



            holder.titleTxtV.setText(storyFeed.getStory(position).getTitle());
            holder.timeTxtV.setText("Posted " + storyFeed.getStory(position).getTime());
            holder.authorTxtV.setText(" By " + storyFeed.getStory(position).getAuthor());
            holder.scoreTxtV.setText(storyFeed.getStory(position).getScore() + " Points ");
            holder.commentB.setText(Integer.toString(storyFeed.getStory(position).getNumberComments()));
            try {
                holder.domTxtV.setText("(" + storyFeed.getStory(position).getURLDomain() + ")");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            holder.commentB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent showComments = new Intent(getActivity(), CommentActivity.class);
                    getActivity().startActivity(showComments);
                }
            });

            holder.detailsLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent showDetails = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailWebActivity.class);
                    Bundle detailsBundle = new Bundle();
                    //detailsBundle.putSerializable("newsFeed", storyFeed);
                    showDetails.putExtra("news",storyFeed);
                    showDetails.putExtras(detailsBundle);
                    showDetails.putExtra("position", position);
                    getActivity().startActivity(showDetails);
                }
            });



            return listItem;

        }
    }



}
```

#### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.material.tdapps.hackernews" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/HackerNewsTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.CommentActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_comment"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.material.tdapps.hackernews.activity.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.DetailWebActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_detail_web"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.material.tdapps.hackernews.activity.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `setRetainInstance(true)` will prevent the `Fragment` from being re-created.  But, right now the `Activity` is *always* re-creating the `DrawerFragment` and forcefully re-creating the `HomeFragment`, resulting in the behavior you are seeing.  In your `Activity.onCreate()` check the `savedInstanceState` is `null`.  If it is, create your `Fragment`s.  If not, then don't as the system will automatically restore them.

Comment: So, if we make this more specific to my code, you are saying to do:
`if( savedInstanceState == null){
    displayView(0);
} else {  
    //do nothing 
}`

Answer (score 0):

You always create a new `Fragment` inside your `displayView` method. Instead, you should use `FragmentManager` to find your fragment by Id or by Tag, and then put it inside your container view.

Please refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentByTag(java.lang.String)

**Edit**

Actually @Larry Schiefer is right, you don't even need to find a fragment, just check the saved instance state whether it's null or not.